# Ubuntu - Folder replaced by lost+found/ on raid1 disks

Tags: ubuntu, raid, fsck

Running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

I have setup a RAID1 on disks sdb & sdc (md0) following strictly this [tutorial](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/raid_logiciel) which I guess is very classical. I loaded data on my disk for archive purposes.

A few days later the server wouldn't boot with the following error :

“Continue to wait; Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery”

I found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot) adding nobootwait to fstab file. The server rebooted fine and the drive was mounted again.

Many files are missing and lost+found/ dir appeared, but it is empty (I only looked 2 months later - the server was not used in the meantime).

Is there a way to recover the files beyond the fsck that apparently didn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't simple, but you can recover files from a lost+found directory.  I found this page that gives a lengthy example of file recovery:

http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/09/how-to-recover-files-from-lostfound-after-fsck-in-linux-how-i-did-it-in-ubuntu/comment-page-1/